# find sth to doing?

Tags: grammar

I saw this sentence in *Rick & Morty*

> We just found a back door to getting off this rock.

I'm confused why the *"ing"* was used here? Shouldn't it be *"to get off"*?

Can anyone answer this question? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The word "getting" is being used in this case as a gerund, not a participle and not part of a "to"-infinitive. A gerund is created by using the "-ing" suffix on a verb, which may then be included in a phrase within which it behaves like any verb, but in which the phrase as a whole is then used as a noun. Thus:

> Quietly raising lions is difficult.

The word "raising" is qualified by an adverb, as any verb may be, and "lions" is the object of that verb, but the phrase as a whole, "quietly raising lions", is then used as a noun, which is the subject of the sentence—the thing asserted to be difficult.

The phrase "getting off this rock" is similar: "off this rock" is a prepositional phrase acting as an adverb qualifying the verb "get". The whole phrase, "getting off this rock", is then used as a noun, in this case as the object of the proposition "to".

> "The key to solving these problems is this: . . . "

That is perhaps a somewhat more typical instance.

Answer (score 4):

***The back door to (doing) something*** is a noun phrase that is

> used to refer to an *indirect way of achieving something*, especially so that people do not know about it and so cannot object to it ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/back-door))

As you can see, it requires the preposition ***TO*** just as you say *the door **to** the back garden*.

As @MHardy already stated, ***getting off this rock*** is a noun phrase functioning as the object of the preposition ***TO***.

Though instances of this phrase being used with a gerund is not particularly common, it is nevertheless encountered. e.g.

> My hope and belief is that that was the Government’s intention, because if it is not it is simply ****a back door to doing*** away with home education*. ([Hansard](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/ld200809/ldhansrd/text/90622-gc0003.htm))

> Internships: ***The Back Door to Doing*** What You Like ([military.com](https://www.military.com/veteran-jobs/career-advice/job-hunting/internships-the-back-door-to-doing-what-you-like.html))